# What has changed on the site?

Tags: python, automation, monitor

i want to know if there is a way i monitor a site for changes that i dont only get the message "something changed", that i get what has changed too.

My code right now is:

```
url = Request('https://stackoverflow.com', 
              headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
  
response = urlopen(url).read()
  
currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()
print("running")
time.sleep(10)
while True:
    try:
        response = urlopen(url).read()
          
        currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()
          
        time.sleep(30)
          
        response = urlopen(url).read()
          
        newHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()
  
        if newHash == currentHash:
            continue
  
        else:
            print("something changed")
  
            response = urlopen(url).read()
  
            currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()
  
            time.sleep(30)
            continue
              
    except Exception as e:
        print("error")
```

Comment: First, you need to define what you want to monitor then it's more focused. Otherwise, that may require real-time checks to things as broad as HTML tags?

Comment: Have you considered the SO RSS feed?  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381154/2711811 or if the site of interest has an RSS feed (perhaps the SO was just an example?).